# Join table group by with sort desc

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 table

Table 1

```
id | value 
-----------
1  |  a 
2  |  b  
3  |  c 
4  |  d
```

Table 2

```
id | table1_id | date
------------------------
1  |   1       | 01-01-2020 1:00:00
2  |   1       | 01-01-2020 2:00:00
3  |   1       | 05-01-2020 1:00:00 (*)
4  |   2       | 05-01-2020 1:00:00
5  |   3       | 06-01-2020 1:00:00
6  |   3       | 06-01-2020 2:00:00 (*)
7  |   2       | 07-01-2020 1:00:00 (*)
```

I want to join table 1 to table 2. get row of table 2 is max value date and group by table1_id

Like exxample, i want get data like this

```
id | value  | table1_id | date
-------------------------------------------------
1  |  a     |     1     | 05-01-2020 1:00:00
2  |  b     |     2     | 07-01-2020 1:00:00  
3  |  c     |     1     | 06-01-2020 2:00:00 
4  |  d     |    NULL   | NULL
```

I tryed like this, but not work true

```
SELECT tb1.*, tb2.* FROM table1 AS tb1 
LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT * FROM table2 ORDER BY date DESC ) AS tb2 
ON tb1.id = tb2.table1_id
GROUP BY table1_id
```

Can someone help me ? Thanks all <3

Comment: . . Why does `table1_id` have the value of `1` in the third row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old school way of doing this in MySQL might be to join to a subquery which finds the maximum date in the second table for each `table1_id`:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.value,
    t2.table1_id,
    t2.date
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t2.table1_id, t2.date
    FROM table2 t2
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT table1_id, MAX(date) AS max_date
        FROM table2
        GROUP BY table1_id
    ) t
        ON t.table1_id = t2.table1_id AND
           t.max_date = t2.date
) t2
    ON t2.table1_id = t1.id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you <3 
It work for me
But i don't want get row 4 ( because table_id is null )

Comment: Can you check again with new comment ?

Comment: I won't edit my answer at this point, but you could just change the outer left join in my answer to an inner join.  That would filter off the fourth row.  [See the updated demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e691c016dc798bd1dc94bf561e78a0f1).

Comment: <3 Thank you very much, happy codingggg

Answer (score 0):

You can also use window function as below

```
SELECT tb1.*, tb2.table1_id, tb2.date 
FROM table1 AS tb1 
LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT table2.*,
            row_number() over(partition by table1_id ORDER BY date DESC) as seq_num
FROM table2 ) AS tb2 
ON tb1.id = tb2.table1_id
Where tb2.seq_num = 1 ;
```

Here is a demo - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f52a5a930411dcc04900a1a5bacfe6e9. The demo contains both NULL and not NULL versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT id, value, table1_id, max(date) date
FROM
  (SELECT t1.id, t1.value, t2.table1_id, t2.date
     FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
       ON t1.id = t2.table1_id
  ) qry
GROUP BY id, value, table1_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you use window functions for this -- assuming you want mulple columns.  This looks like:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by table1_id order by date DESC) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2 
     on t1.id = t2.table1_id and seq_num = 1 ;
```

However, if you just want one column -- and the `table1_id` is redundant so I see no need to include it -- then a correlated subquery is often the fastest method:

```
select t1.*,
       (select max(t2.date) from table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.table1_id)
from table1 t1;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `table2(table1_id, date)`.